# What is the difference between sha1(),password_hash() and hash()?

Tags: php, hash

Can someone explain a little bit difference about `sha1()`, `password_hash()` and `hash()`?

Comment: sha1() uses the sha1 message digest algorithm to create a hash; password_hash() generates a salted hash using the most secure algorithm accessible to PHP, hash() uses a user-specified message digest algorithm to create a hash.... reading the PHP docs tells you what these functions do